# Font Icons not working on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use Visual VC Addons to build my product pages but font icons of this plugins do not show up.

Sample url: http://megatheme.ir/zephyr

I use IMPREZA wordpress theme

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1: Place a file at location**

Please check this file is at proper location.Put Defaults.css in specified path.

```
/wp-content/uploads/smile_fonts/Defaults/Defaults.css
```

Add  missing font file :

```
/wp-content/themes/MegaThemeIR/css/font/IRANSansWeb.woff
```

**Case 2: Load using a CDN**

For IRANSansWeb.woff,

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: @Mostafa Please add two file.Above font are not there so that it occur.

Comment: @Mostafa,I have suggestion for you please sort out that console error.and check you site in google page insight for best result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't because don't work Font Icon in your website.

But if you want use one that many people use because work well you can try [Font Awesome Icon](http://fontawesome.io)

- Go [here on the website](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) and download the Icon Font and add in your folder inside `href="//megatheme.ir/wp-content/themes/MegaThemeIR"`
- Put this part of crude in your `<Head>` `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">` where it's write `path/to/` write your url, like `//megatheme.ir/wp-content/themes/MegaThemeIR/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css` or similar

  If you use the class name you need the icon will work sure.